# invalid command 's' perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: php, apache, centos

I'm trying to configure Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7, but I do not understand the error:

```
Invalid command 's' perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What can I do?

Comment: Can you please post the entire message? It should show where exactly this 's' command occurs. Most likely it is in a .htaccess file.

Comment: `AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:`

Comment: OK, then you should check what is on the first line of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: `s is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.`

Comment: It seems I have identified the cause ... someone has deleted `#
# Thi`